# Network port not showing after running BasicOTA in ArduinoIDE for ESP8266 on Mac

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I've just recently got an **NodeMCUv3 ESP8266** and I've been trying to use the **Arduino IDE 1.8.8** to program it on my **Mac**.
I've successfully installed **ch340*** drivers and I can flash the **ESP8266** using USB wire cable.

But after flashing the **BasicOTA** example (modified to connect to my **WiFi**), I am not seeing my **NodeMCU** listed as a network port. I only see a list of Serial ports even after restarting **ArduinoIDE** and **NodeMCU**.

I tried **Bonjour Browser** to discover my **NodeMCU** device and I cannot see it on the net as well.

Could you please suggest any ideas what could be the problem for appearing the network port for **NodeMCU** device in the **ArduinoIDE**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding the line

> MDNS.update();

into loop() function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows
1. Install Bonjour
2. Exit the IDE, Disable the network adapters, Enable & connect the network adapters, Start the IDE
3. Disable IPV6 on your network adapters
4. Open the INBOUND port for Python.exe (with the full path)

Hopefully if you do all this, you should be able to do OTA